# How to formalize the syntactic replacement between $(x,y)\in f$ and $f(x)=y$ for a function $f$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4529002/834062) on the explanation of how we establish the syntactical replacement for functions.

Define

$Image(f,x) = f(x) = \{z:\exists y(z\in y \wedge (x,y)\in f)\}$

If we assume $f$ is a function and $x\in dom(f)$ then we can derive that $(x,y)\in f\Leftrightarrow f(x)=y$.

I have scoured the internet (mostly Wikipedia, niche math encyclopedias, Wolfram and of course, the StackExchange) for anything on the equivalence between the statements but I haven’t found anything. As per my previous question, the answers told me that it’s just a common notation/syntactical replacement. If anything, I would’ve expected this to be an exercise, but I have never come across it.

So why is this equivalence just glossed over as common notation without much justification when you can clearly derive it with some set theory?

I know with how I defined $Image(f,x)$, then it corresponds to the empty set without $x\in dom(f)$. So is there any way to generate a class $I(f,x)$ s.t if $f$ is a function, then $(x,y)\in f\Leftrightarrow I(f,x)=y$?; this case not necessarily having $x\in dom(f)$.

Comment: You are confused about something. $\text{Image}(f,x) = \{y : (x,y) \in f\}$. That $z \in y$ formula requires the elements of the codomain to be considered as sets, and would be appropriate for $\bigcup \text{Image}(f,x)$, not $\text{Image}(f,x)$ itself. If $f$ is a function (not an arbitrary subset of the product of the domain and codomain), then $\text{Image}(f,x)$ is a singleton set, and $f(x)$ denotes the lone element in $\text{Image}(f,x)$, not the set itself.